# How to get AutoMapper to use interface mappings and concrete mappings

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper

I'm trying to get AutoMapper to update all properties on my object from the interface level (DRY approach) but only the interface properties are updating:

I've tried looking into and messing around with the include paths from the AutoMapper documentation but it isn't working the way I would expect and not sure if it's even relevant: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance

Here are my models:

```
public interface IEntity {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IDatedEntity : IEntity {
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}

public interface IBMSEntity : IDatedEntity {
    string Notes { get; set; }
    bool Active { get; set; }

}

public class ProjectStatus : IBMSEntity {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public StatusType Type { get; set; }

    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    #region Interface Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

And here is the the portion of code that accepts the IDatedEntity and maps it across for the purpose of updating using EntityFramework:

```
public class BaseDatedEntityUpdate<T> : BaseEntityUpdate<T>, IUpdate<T> where T : class, IDatedEntity {

    public BaseDatedEntityUpdate(BMSContext context, IValidationDictionary validation) : base(context, validation) { }

    public override T Update(T entity) {
        //setting - I'd like to put this on the base mappings also
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        entity.DateModified = now;

        //mapping
        var original = dbSet.Find(entity.Id);
        Mapper.Map(entity, original);

        return original;
    }
}
```

I have 2 options for my map configuration:

**Option 1:**
I put my ignore properties on the base type:

```
        //testing base/interface maps
        Mapper.CreateMap<IDatedEntity, IDatedEntity>()
            .ForMember(x => x.DateCreated, y=> {
                y.UseDestinationValue();
                y.Ignore();
            });

        Mapper.CreateMap<ProjectStatus, ProjectStatus>();
```

This will not ignore DateCreated so I have to change `Mapper.Map(entity, original);` to `Mapper.Map<IDatedEntity, IDatedEntity>(entity, original);` but then I have the problem where my project status properties (such as Name, Type and IsDefault) are not getting mapped across.

**Option 2:** 
I put the mappings on my concrete type:

```
        //testing base/interface maps
        Mapper.CreateMap<IDatedEntity, IDatedEntity>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<ProjectStatus, ProjectStatus>()
            .ForMember(x => x.DateCreated, y=> {
                y.UseDestinationValue();
                y.Ignore();
            });
```

This technically works the way I want it to, but it isn't very DRY.

**Question:**

Is there a way to apply the mappings to the base type and keep my code DRY?
I.e. I want to use Option 1, whereby all ProjectStatus (and any other derivatives of IDatedEntity) properties are mapped across - without having to create detailed concrete type mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe its not as dry as you might like and maybe it's a little overkill ;p but you could map each type with just a little bit of reflection and a loop or two.

Also you might be able to specify just one assembly - I've just taken a brute force approach incase you need a few.

```
public interface ITest
{
    DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mapMethod = typeof (Program).GetMethod("Map", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var genericMapMethod in from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                         from type in assembly.DefinedTypes
                                         where typeof (ITest).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                                         select mapMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type))
        {
            genericMapMethod.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
        }

        var test = new Test {Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()};
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        var test2 = new Test();

        Mapper.Map(test, test2);

        Console.WriteLine(test2.Guid);
        Console.WriteLine(test.Guid == test2.Guid);
        Console.WriteLine(test.CreatedAt == test2.CreatedAt);

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Map<T>() where T : ITest
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<T, T>()
        .ForMember(x => x.CreatedAt, y => {
            y.UseDestinationValue();
            y.Ignore();
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if that was a step in the right direction.
Hope it helps.

Comment: 2 questions, does this actually work? And am I correct in thinking I only need to run this on application start up to register the maps?

Comment: It does work, you can just copy paste this into a console app and run it to test.  And yes you can run this just once.

Just note because there is some reflection the startup will be a little slower

Comment: It's a web App so start-up isn't an issue, you're a genius man thank you!